# VBA Selenium loop through each table

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, loops

Using Selenium for Excel, I need to loop through each table in the webpage to extract each table.
There are usually 7 to 10 tables on the page.

The current code I have extracts the first table, nine time's over (based on count).
How can I extract each table once?

```
Dim bot As New ChromeDriver, tbl As Selenium.TableElement, LRow As Long

Const sURL As String = "https://www.racingandsports.com/form-guide/thoroughbred/australia/sale/2021-10-06/race-tips"

With bot
    .Get sURL

    Set tbl = .FindElementById("rank_table").AsTable
    r = .FindElementsById("rank_table").Count
    For i = 1 To r

    Sheets("Import").Select
    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    tbl.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("A" & LRow + 2)
Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Why your code is copying the first table for 9 times?**

- In that page, there are total 9 elements are having `id` value as `rank_table`
- You have mentioned `Set tbl = .FindElementById("rank_table").AsTable` outside of the `for` loop and as there are multiple `id's` with same value it picks the first element always if we don't specify anything.
- In your loop, you are pasting firstly copied table for 9 times.

**Updated code**:

```
Dim bot As New ChromeDriver
Dim tbl As Selenium.TableElement
Dim LRow As Long

Const sURL As String = "https://www.racingandsports.com/form-guide/thoroughbred/australia/sale/2021-10-06/race-tips"

With bot
    .Get sURL
    r = .FindElementsById("rank_table").Count
    For i = 1 To r
    Set tbl = .FindElementByXPath("(//table[@id='rank_table'])[" & i & "]").AsTable
    Sheets("Import").Select
    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    tbl.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import").Range("A" & LRow + 2)
Next i
End With
```

> **What changes I did to make it work?**

- Created a dynamic `xPath` to iterate through all the tables.
- Called the `.FindElementByXPath("xPath").AsTable` inside the loop.

Comment: Nandan, First thank you for your time and update ... this works perfectly. Secondly, thank you for the clear explanation. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css id selector and gather with a method returning `WebElements` rather than `WebElement` e.g.

```
Dim tables As Selenium.WebElements

Set tables = .FindElementsByCss("#rank_table")
```

Then `For Each tbl` that collection, and use tweak your existing code to write out each table to next free row (+ any empty row gap in between tables).

You could also use the `.FindElementsById("rank_table")` as it appears that method exists, though I have never used it.

Comment: Thank you very much QHarr

Comment: you are most welcome